# How to change max duration or refresh AWS session in Airflow 2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x

Can we increase session duration or refresh session for AWS in Apache Airflow v 2.0.2 when we use assume role like in AWS connection extra?

```
{
  "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/airflow-connection-role",
  "region_name": "ap-southeast-1"
}
```

I understand that default max duration is 1 hour and refreshable credential is supported in Airflow 2.1.

- https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8301
- https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16771

But I am currently using Airflow v2.0.2 in MWAA (Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow). so we can not use the option above.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/airflow-versions.html#airflow-versions-v222
- Airflow version v2.0.2
- apache-airflow-providers-amazon==1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In apache-airflow-providers-amazon==1.3.0, AwsBaseHook will take kwargs for assuming the role. Set `extras` in your connection to

```
{
  "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/airflow-connection-role",
  "region_name": "ap-southeast-1",
  "assume_role_kwargs": "{ 'DurationSeconds': 7200 }"
}
```

In the issue you reference, one comment says

> After digging a little into the code, it appears that #7619 introduced the ability to set arbitrary kwargs for the assume role function call.

Here are the lines in Airflow supporting this.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0823d46a7f267f2e45195a175021825367938add/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/base_aws.py#L92
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0823d46a7f267f2e45195a175021825367938add/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/base_aws.py#L172